# Can I use sequel code to query data with my Node.js server

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am taking a PostgreSQL course, and the instructor is teaching sequel code, I just want to know if it's possible use my Node.js server to query data using sequel code, because I can't find any resource  that do that, they only use ORMS, like Prisma.., if it's not possible to use sequel code in Node.js then what's the point of learning it? and if it's possible, link me to some resources.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use an ORM (tho preferable, since they usually help you with sanitizing, error handling and such), you could write low-level queries with something like [pg](https://node-postgres.com/)

```
// callback
client.query('SELECT NOW() as now', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
  }
})
// promise
client
  .query('SELECT NOW() as now')
  .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

And usually it easier to understand what the ORM is doing (and why) if you understand the underlying database.